# How can I solve the Error: 358 when activating MATLAB R2019b?

Tags: matlab

["Error 358: The license file expiration date has passed. In order to activate this license, the license file expiration date must be set to a future date."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuXMQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I solve the Error: 358 when activating MATLAB R2019b?

Your license expired back on April 30th 2020, you will need to purchase a new license, in order to continue to use the product in question.